# ColdFusion cfhttp request slow than cfquetry

Tags: node.js, performance, coldfusion

I'm trying to improve my application. It was built in ColdFusion and I'm rewriting the backend in NodeJS. I create a NodeJS API with Express and it connects to MySQL database.

For example, I have a controller that gets data from database and return a json.
Below are the resumed code for my NodeJS backend

```
const data = await MyClass.getData();
return res.json(data);
```

And MyClass is the model

```
module.exports = class MyClass {
   async getData() {
      const res = await db.execute(`Select * From myTable`);
      return res[0];
   }
}
```

Then in my CF application, I replace the previous cfquery

```
<cfquery name="getData" datasource="myDS">
   Select * From myTable
</cfquery>
```

To a http request:

```
<cfhttp result="result" method="GET" useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#"
   url="http://mywebsite.com/NodeJS/getData" >
</cfhttp>
<cfset data = deserializeJSON(result.Filecontent) />
```

It works perfectly, but I noticed (looking the firebug Network tab that the time and size to load the file with the cfhttp is bigger than the one using cfquery.

Is cfhttp slow? What would be the best way to move my application backend to NodeJS and get a better performance?

Thanks

Comment: There would always be extra time and size as you are adding tons of additional overheads. Cfhttp is not slow, but this depends on what your comparing. You will have the time of the http request, the time for node to produce the result and then how it is sent back. Is the data compressed etc (gzip). Cfquery has one efficient job, what you are changing too is not comparable.

Comment: Thank you. So, there is not a way to transform my application backend to NodeJS

Comment: It's not that `cfhttp` is particularly slow when compared to other means of generating an http request, it's that you've added a layer of abstraction by creating an API that wasn't there before and then executing an http request that wasn't needed before. You now have: `browser http request -> server http request -> run DB query -> http response to server -> http response to browser` - the double hop is obviously going to be slower than what you had before:  `browser http request -> run DB query -> http response to browser`